# Laravel Eloquent - Unable to fetch columns using array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using laravel eloquent to fetch the data from multiple columns. I am using array to fetch the data from multiple columns. For simplicity, I am showing the data from two columns.

Here is my database table which has `callee_number` and `caller_number`:

[image]

Here is my code where I am using array for fetching the columns:

```
    $paramArray = $params->all();

    $Caller_number = "";
    $Callee_number = "";

    if (isset($paramArray['Caller_number']) && $paramArray['Caller_number'] != '') {
        $Caller_number = $params->input('Caller_number');
    }
    if (isset($paramArray['Callee_number']) && $paramArray['Callee_number'] != '') {
        $Callee_number = $params->input('Callee_number');
    }

    if($Caller_number!=null){
        $querypart[] = "caller_number=$Caller_number";
    }
    if($Callee_number!=null){
        $querypart[] = "callee_number=$Callee_number";
    }


    $FinalQueryPart = '';
    if (!empty($querypart)) {
        
        $Seprator = "";
        foreach ($querypart as $querypartValue) {
            $FinalQueryPart .= $Seprator . $querypartValue;
            $Seprator = " AND ";
        }
    }

    $FinalQueryPart = trim($FinalQueryPart); //Output: "caller_number=783 AND callee_number=77"
```

However I get the error after I run the following code after above code:

```
    $gets = Tbcdrnew::where(function ($query) use ($FinalQueryPart) {
        $query->MIN('uniqueid')->where($FinalQueryPart)
            ->from('cdrnew');
            
    })->groupBy('uniqueid')->orderBy('Start_Date','DESC')->get();
```

The error is as follows:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'caller_number=783 AND callee_number=77' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `cdrnew` where (`caller_number=783 AND callee_number=77` is null) group by `uniqueid`
```

Not getting what is wrong in my code. Can anybody correct me ?

Comment: Unknown column `'caller_number=783 AND callee_number=77'`

Comment: Change `where()` to `whereRaw()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you commited a mistake in the query.
Replace the following lines by those ones:

```php
if($Caller_number!=null){
    $querypart[] = "caller_number = '$Caller_number'";
}
if($Callee_number!=null){
    $querypart[] = "callee_number = '$Callee_number'";
}
```

(Note the single quotes on the `$Caller_number` & `$Callee_number`).

Also, using the `whereRaw()` method instead of `where()` as it is suggested in a response comment.

Comment: @Shreeniwas sorry, I placed the quotes on the other side. Try again

Comment: But requires whereRaw

Comment: Yes, you are right. Another possibility would be to check manually if the `caller_number` is not empty and adding the `where()` clause to the `$query` object (and the same with the other var), it's a bit tricky. I think the current implementation is good enough :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding an answer suggesting a method to simplify your code by eliminating all the `if` conditions using Laravel collection methods.

```
$query = Tbcdrnew::query();                           //start a query string based on Tbcdrnew model OR you could do DB::table('cdrnew');
collect($paramArray)->filter(function($value, $key){  //convert paramArray into a collection
    return $value != '';                              //filter all null and empty values
})->each(function($value, $key) use ($query){         //iterate through all filtered values
    $query->where(strtolower($key), $value);          //assuming array key is always column key in lowercase
});
$result = $query->groupBy('uniqueid')->orderBy('start_date','desc')->get();
```

I'm not sure if `$query->MIN` you have in your original query is a valid query builder function.